# Introduction to Multiple Curve construction

Tags: multicurve

Could someone please share a good starting point to learn about Multiple curves? More than exact theorems and proofs, I am mainly interested in reading about -

1. How to build multiple curves - how to bootstrap simultaneously etc
2. For a given swap trade, how will my risk look like on these curves.
3. How should the curves handle different combinations of collateral/netting, forward settle etc.

The closest I got by searching on forums was [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/214/paradoxes-in-quantitative-finance/217#217), but I'm looking for something more specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've always enjoyed OpenGamma's white paper: [MULTIPLE CURVE CONSTRUCTION](https://quant.opengamma.io/Multiple-Curve-Construction-OpenGamma.pdf). It's a solid starting point from an implementation perspective.

Andersen & Piterbarg's "Interest Rate Modeling" (Volume 1) also has a good chapter on this topic that's pretty easy to follow.

Comment: Does anyone have a PDF copy of the OpenGamma's white paper: MULTIPLE CURVE CONSTRUCTION? The link above is not valid anymore. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the seminal reference in this matter is:

> Masaaki Fujii, Yasufumi Shimada & Akihiko Takahashi (2009). "A note on construction of multiple swap curves with and without collateral". *FSA Research Review*, Vol. 6, 2010.

I think it gives a good understanding on how to proceed.