# What are your list of concept or model in standard textbooks that are always reliable to used in working?

Tags: finance, books, big-list

What are your list of concept or model in standard textbooks that are always reliable to used in working?

As opposed back to this: [What concepts are the most dangerous ones in quantitative finance work?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/156/what-concepts-are-the-most-dangerous-ones-in-quantitative-finance-work)

Comment: Let's try this community wiki thing.